# Trying to check for a powershell module, install if it doesn't exist, then rerun the same script

Tags: powershell

So I am trying to write a script that will check if the user has a certain module installed, and if it doesn't, to install it, then rerun itself.

When I try to run this, the script just keeps rerunning and trying to install. I have to use a setup.exe and I have it waiting for the window to cl

```
    $mypath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
    $Path = Split-Path $mypath -Parent
    $Location = "$Path" + "\setup.exe"
    
    
    
    if (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name ActiveRolesManagementShell) {
     Write-Host "QAD Is installed"
    pause
    } 
    else{
    
    
    Write-Host "Installing QAD"
    
        Start-Process $Location
        Wait-Process -Name "setup"
    Pause
    $CommandLine = "-File `"" + $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path + "`" " + $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments
    Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell.exe -Verb Runas -ArgumentList $CommandLine
    Pause
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, modules are installed using `Install-Module`. Then you might need to tell PowerShell about it for the **current** session to be able to use it.

```
if (-not(Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name ActiveRolesManagementShell)) {
    Install-Module ActiveRolesManagementShell
    Import-Module ActiveRolesManagementShell # Might not be needed
} 
 
# Add code that uses ActiveRolesManagementShell module
```

But with regards to ActiveRolesManagementShell, what version are you using?
The old Quest module was probably meant to work on PowerShell v2. And I can't find a current version...

Comment: I can't use Import-Module, we have been provided a file for the install, I have access to a Setup.exe and an MSI file, If I can figure out how to install either, then rerun the script without it looping constantly then it should work.

Comment: If it requires an MSI (which is a legacy setup method for modules) then you might have to run the import-module to force the current session to see it.
It might even be possible that you have to you `Add-PSSnapin` to make legacy modules work...

Comment: So I decided to just force the user to restart the script manually, once they install the module through the installer, it will tell them to restart powershell. Unless I get anything from this thread, I will do this.

Comment: What happened if you tried `import-module` after installing it? Did it show?

Comment: The Import would fail

Comment: Fail as in not found or as in errors during import?
Is there any notion about using legacy Add-PSSnapin instead in the documentation?